# Query Store with Stale Query cleanup based configuration / goes to read-only and assumes RW after few hours

Tags: sql-server

Database is 5TB (data and indexes). It support AX Dynamics ERP.

Cleanup is based on Stale Query Threshold (3 days).
Size Based Cleanup has proven useless for this solution.

[Last two weeks (QS state and it's free storage %)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpoKb.png)

| QS SETTINS | values |
| --- | --- |
| current_storage_size_MB | RW |
| free storage % | 35 |

| MONITORING |  |
| --- | --- |
| data_flush_interval_min | 20 |
| stats_collection_interval | 30 min |

| QUERY STORE RETENTION |  |
| --- | --- |
| max_storage_size_GB | 192 |
| max_plans_per_query | 15 |
| size_based_cleanup_mode | OFF |
| stale_query_treshold_days | 3 |
| wait_statistics_capture | ON |

| QUERY STORE CAPTURE MODE |  |
| --- | --- |
| execution_count | 10 |
| stale_treshold | 4 hours |
| total_compile_CPU_time_ms | 1000 |
| total_execution_CPU_time_ms | 100 |

Changes in last 3 weeks:

- additional wait statistics capture was set to ON,
- Changed was retention configuration to use stale query threshold instead size based cleanup.
  Recent change:
- 14th of July, max size was changed from 128 to 192 GB.

Despite Query Store having more than 30% of free storage space it keeps going to read-only mode.
Automatically changes state to RW within few hours.

actual_state_additional_info FROM sys.database_query_store_options doesn't contain any information.

Do you know where log/history for Query Store could be found?